# How can we replace "./." with "-1"

Tags: sed, replace

**Input**:

```
7058    7067    7111    7186    7288    7322    7328    7373
./. ./. ./. ./. ./. 0|0 ./. 0|0
./. ./. 0|0 ./. ./. 0|0 ./. 0|0
./. ./. ./. ./. ./. 0|0 ./. 0|0
./. ./. ./. ./. ./. 0|0 ./. 1|1
```

**Desired output**:

```
7058    7067    7111    7186    7288    7322    7328    7373
-1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0|0 -1  0|0
-1  -1  0|0 -1  -1  0|0 -1  0|0
-1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0|0 -1  0|0
-1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0|0 -1  1|1
```

I have tried `sed -i 's/././-1/g' File_name` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression for that:

```
sed -E 's,./.,-1,g' <(echo './.')
```

You can use delimiters different from `/`, so you don't have to escape them, `.` doesn't have to be excaped if you are using extended regular expressions.

Possible delimiters(there may be others):

- `:`
- `_`
- `,`
- `|`

So in your case:

```
sed -E -i.backup 's,./.,-1,g' File_name
```

, or you are able to escape `.`-s and `/`-s, but that can lead to a mess:

```
sed -i.backup 's/\.\/\./-1/g' File_name
```

Please use an extension name after the `i` flag to make a backup file if you're not sure about the result of the sed command.

Comment: Many thanks for this information and solution

Comment: I'm glad, but I'd be happier, if you accepted it. You can accept the answer by clicking on the pipe. An upvote would make my day better as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's:./.:-1:g' File_name
```

=> 7058 7067 7111 7186 7288 7322 7328 7373 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0|0 -1 0|0 -1 -1 0|0 -1 -1 0|0 -1 0|0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0|0 -1 0|0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0|0 -1 1|1

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your solution, to make it even more clear.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked